# CSS and Image in HTML

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I am learning CSS through the Mozilla Developer Network. I save through Codeanywhere and Dropbox.

My CSS and image are not showing up when I download it. I've checked code, directories and Github examples and still nothing. Any ideas would be appreciated. This is the problem area:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Another Attempt at Coding
    </h1> 
    <img src="HP-Firefox-icon.png" alt="The Firefox logo">
    <p>



      What is your website about? </p>
     <ul>
       <li>Do you like dogs, New York, or Pacman?
</li>
      <li>What does your website look like</li>

 <li>What's the background color?</li> 
       <li>What kind of font is appropriate: formal, cartoony, bold and loud, subtle?</li>
    </ul> 

 <p>
   Read the <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/manifesto/">Mozilla Manifesto</a> 
  </p>
```

Comment: If you save via CodeAnywhere, would you happen to have a public URL where we can see that code running? Could you maybe post a screenshot of the file structure, or the URL to the Github repo you're putting your code in?

Comment: Got the Github "Learning Web Design Code" up but not sure how to transfer my CodeAnywhere information to the new repo. Here is my Github: https://github.com/blurosemd/Learning-Web-Design-Code.git

Answer (score 0):

The path for CSS and image is not correct. Make sure the CSS and image file name is located in same directory and having the same name.

```
<img src="HP-Firefox-icon.png" alt="The Firefox logo">

<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It will only work if you find the correct url for the source files and put it. If you downloaded the example, then make sure all files are downloaded.

Comment: Could you help me by going through the process? I have checked the example and downloaded the picture yet come up with nothing. I have worked with CSS once before and it worked. I'm missing a small detail somewhere..

Comment: @RoseKetring `styles/style.css` It says your CSS file is located in styles folder. And the name of the stylesheet is `style.css`. Do you have style folder and `style.css` file inside it?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I saw my error and now got it working :)